# What is the Problems of my Code in Claim base Authorization ASP.NET CORE WEB API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, jwt

I want to use claim base Authorization in ASP.NET CORE Web API, I think my code is true but, it does not work for me and gives me the error `403 forbidden` however I use the Right Token which has the right claim value in my `AspNetUserClaims` table
here is my Program.cs code

```
//Get Connection String
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opts =>
               opts.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration["connection:connectionString"]));


builder.Services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));

builder.Services.AddMvc();


builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("VIEW",
        policy => policy.RequireClaim("VIEW"));
});

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true);



//JWT Token Setup
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JWT_Secret"]);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x => {
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = false;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
```

here is my UsersLoginController when the user login, this controller generates the Token after successful login

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
   
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
            if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                //Get role assigned to the user
                var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                IdentityOptions _options = new IdentityOptions();

                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                    {
                        new Claim("UserID",user.Id.ToString()),
                        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType,role.FirstOrDefault())
                    }),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.JWT_Secret)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
                return Ok(new { token });
            }
            else
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect." });
        }
    }
```

here is my UsersProfileDetailsController

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Policy = "VIEW")]
        
        public async Task<Object> GetUserProfile()
        {
            string userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            return new
            {
                user.Id,
                user.FirstName,
                user.LastName,
                user.Email,
                user.UserName,
                user.PhotoPath,
                role,
    
            };
        }
```

Now when I login with Admin User  which has the right Claimvalue `VIEW` in the Table `AspNetUserClaims`, it generates the Token for me but when I use this Token to access UserDetails from `UsersProfileDetailsController` it gives me the code `403 forbidden`.
Can anyone help me with how to implement Claims base Authorization and what are my problems?
I use Postman for testing.

Comment: Be aware that there's a difference between "401 - Unathorized" (We don't know who you are) and "403 - Forbidden" (You can't access this). 403 normally mean you are authenticated but not allowed to acces the specific resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you configured authoriztion as below:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("VIEW",
        policy => policy.RequireClaim("VIEW"));
});
```

If you Press F12 and go to definition,you'll find the explaination of
the method
[image]

you added `[Authorize(Policy = "VIEW")]` on your controller, if you want authorize successfully, when you generate the token,you have to add the claim  VIEW

```
Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                    {
                        new Claim("UserID",user.Id.ToString()),
                        //add a new claim named View here
                        new Claim("View",.......),
                        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType,role.FirstOrDefault())
                    }),
```

Comment: Thanks, bro, You solve my Problems